# jQuery - Trigger Click More Than Once

Tags: javascript, jquery

New to jQuery, still learning a lot so I'm sorry if this is a silly question!

I'm able to Trigger a click, but I'd like to run the function over and over again so my carousel keeps rotating itself.

How would I do that?

Here's what I have so far:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.next').trigger('click');
}, 500);
```

Thanks!

Comment: [**setInterval**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval)

Comment: There are better ways to rotate your images. What are you using for a carousel? Prebuilt/downloaded or Homemade? If homemade, post some additional code so we can help.

Comment: Call `setTimeout` again inside the callback.

Comment: Hi James - Here's a link to my Carousel: http://jsfiddle.net/nq7q14db/  I'm just setting myself tasks to help myself learn a little quicker.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by replacing `setTimeout` with [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) to keep repeating the click after the specified timeout.

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('.next').trigger('click');
}, 500);
```

Fair warning, while this will work, **it's a terrible solution**. It would be better to look for an API in your carousel, or add one to trigger a slide.

Comment: Fair warning indeed, please find the function that click is calling and call that instead.